# Cannot load UICollectionView with own IndexPath, also IndexPath gets randomly added when printing it in cell for item at:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a Gallery app, very similar to the one already built-in in iOS Devices. I added some random images as source data and I set up two View Controllers, Both being Collection views but the first one to display all the images available and the second one to view each image individually. The problem starts when I navigate to the second view controller (Where you can see the individual image), when I try to scroll horizontally, the same photo always appears, it never changes or iterates through the imagesArray (which provides the source for UICollectionView Data Source). Even though there are four images in an UIImageArray, when I navigate to the second view controller I can scroll back and forward, but the same photo always appears. I expect it to behave in such a way that the user can scroll back and forward and see each image in the array (The same thing in the iOS Gallery App)

The app is supposed to load the image the user selected, it does but when I scroll it stays in the same image. The app knows exactly what image to retrieve in imagesArray with the indexPath given in the first view controller and pushed through to the second one in a prepareForSegue method, when I do so, the image that the user selected gets shown, but only that image. That reference is stored in a variable called "passedContentOffSet" which references the indexPath of the previous ViewController. Then to populate the data of the collection view of the second View Controller, I use passedContentOffSet.item, however it happens the problem mentioned above. I changed this to simply indexPath.item and now the collection view can scroll through all the images available but it always starts with the first image, never with the image that the user selected.

First View Controller (Where all the images are shown Vertically)

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {
    let context =   (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    struct Storyboard {
        static let photoCell = "PhotoCell"
        static let sectionHeaderView = "SectionHeaderView"
        static let showDetailVC = "ShowImageDetail"

        static let leftAndRightPaddings: CGFloat = 2.0
        static let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 3.0


    }

    var images:[UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "facebook")!, UIImage(named: "pinterest")!, UIImage(named: "linkedin")!, UIImage(named: "amazon")! ]

    @IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!

    var selectedIndexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.width
        let itemWidth = (collectionViewWidth - Storyboard.leftAndRightPaddings) / Storyboard.numberOfItemsPerRow
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photo", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        let selectedItem = images[indexPath.row]

        cell.userImageView.image = selectedItem

        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDescription", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToDescription" {

            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ImagePreviewVC
            destinationVC.images = images
            destinationVC.passedContentOffset = selectedIndexPath

        }
    }
}
```

Now, the Second View Controller, where the app is supposed to show the user the individual image that the user selected, and also be able to scroll horizontally to see the other images

```
class ImagePreviewVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {
    var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var imgArray = [UIImage]()
    var passedContentOffset = IndexPath()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.black

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing=0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing=0
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        myCollectionView.delegate=self
        myCollectionView.dataSource=self
        myCollectionView.register(ImagePreviewFullViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        myCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: passedContentOffset, at: .left, animated: true)

        self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)

        myCollectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing(rawValue: UIViewAutoresizing.RawValue(UInt8(UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth.rawValue) | UInt8(UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight.rawValue)))
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImagePreviewFullViewCell
        cell.imgView.image=imgArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        guard let flowLayout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }

        flowLayout.itemSize = myCollectionView.frame.size

        flowLayout.invalidateLayout()

        myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        let offset = myCollectionView.contentOffset
        let width  = myCollectionView.bounds.size.width

        let index = round(offset.x / width)
        let newOffset = CGPoint(x: index * size.width, y: offset.y)

        myCollectionView.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated: false)

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
            self.myCollectionView.reloadData()

            self.myCollectionView.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated: false)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The cell class:

```
class ImagePreviewFullViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var scrollImg: UIScrollView!
    var imgView: UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        scrollImg = UIScrollView()
        scrollImg.delegate = self
        scrollImg.alwaysBounceVertical = false
        scrollImg.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
        scrollImg.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        scrollImg.flashScrollIndicators()

        scrollImg.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollImg.maximumZoomScale = 4.0

        let doubleTapGest = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTapScrollView(recognizer:)))
        doubleTapGest.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        scrollImg.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGest)

        self.addSubview(scrollImg)

        imgView = UIImageView()
        imgView.image = UIImage(named: "user3")
        scrollImg.addSubview(imgView!)
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }

    @objc func handleDoubleTapScrollView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if scrollImg.zoomScale == 1 {
            scrollImg.zoom(to: zoomRectForScale(scale: scrollImg.maximumZoomScale, center: recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)), animated: true)
        } else {
            scrollImg.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func zoomRectForScale(scale: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
        var zoomRect = CGRect.zero
        zoomRect.size.height = imgView.frame.size.height / scale
        zoomRect.size.width  = imgView.frame.size.width  / scale
        let newCenter = imgView.convert(center, from: scrollImg)
        zoomRect.origin.x = newCenter.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0)
        zoomRect.origin.y = newCenter.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0)
        return zoomRect
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.imgView
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        scrollImg.frame = self.bounds
        imgView.frame = self.bounds
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        scrollImg.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I expect the user can actually select the image in the first view controller and that image be shown individually in the second view controller, also that from there, the user can swipe right or left and see the other images in the array, just as the iOS Gallery app does.

Comment: Are you sure that in the `ImagePreviewVC`'s `viewDidLoad` method your `imgArray` and `passedContentOffset` properties are well set? You should reload the data and `scrollToItem` in the `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that and the problem persists